# How to display value dropdown when I selected

Tags: html

I have a newbie question in `php`
When I Select value from `dropdown`
automated that the value is output in the `textbox`
for example..

```
<select></select>
  <option>John</option>
</select>
```

When i select john
automatic 
the information of john output on a textbox

How to do this?
thanks in advance..
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: This is HTML not php..

Comment: you need to use javascript to play with the html elements!

Comment: Yes
this a example
But I dont know how to do in php
so i ask?

Answer (score 0):

You're speaking of something that is typically done on the client side via `javascript`. `PHP` on the other hand is a `server side scripting language`.

If the information about John is stored in a database somewhere you would be doing an `ajax` call to a `php function` that retrieves and returns your desired information from the database. You would then use `javascript` to manipulate the `DOM` to insert the returned information into your textbox.

I hope this helps and gets you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not in [php](/questions/tagged/php) scope, you just need some Javascript to do it:

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/y545R/)

HTML:

```
<select id="cbxName">
    <option value="Join">John</option>
    <option value="TrungDQ">TrungDQ</option>
</select>
<input id="txtName" type="text" value=""/>
```

Javascript:

```
var e = document.getElementById("cbxName");
e.onchange = function() {
    var strName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("txtName").value = strName;
}
```